.NET Aspire - How to execute command from Aspire App Host inside container
in .NET Aspire I'm trying to run a command into the docker container
but I don't know how to do it
for example run mongod --port 27000 command
and this is my Aspire AppHost program.cs file
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var mongo = builder.AddMongoDB("mymongo").AddDatabase("mydb");

var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireApp3_ApiService>("apiservice")
    .WithReference(mongo);

builder. Build().Run();


you can use WithArgs() to execute your command like this
var mongo = builder.AddMongoDB("mymongo")
.WithArgs("mongod", "--port", "27000")
.AddDatabase("mydb");

and the result is

and You can also use it for AddProject like this
var apiService = builder.AddProject<Projects.AspireApp3_ApiService>("apiservice")
    .WithArgs("dotnet","--help")
    .WithReference(mongo);

